# Is there a sign() function in xPath

Tags: math, xpath

Is there a `sign()` function available in xPath? So that the following are all true:

```
sign(-2) == -1
sign(-1) == -1
sign( 0) ==  0
sign(+1) ==  1
sign(+2) ==  1
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such function in XPath. You can check [list of available functions here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/). If you have some specific issue - update your question with issue description

Comment: Please always cite a specific version of XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. The workaround depends on which version of XPath you are using.